# Benchmarks of Apache Geode

Tags: redis, benchmarking, hazelcast, geode

I'm doing some research and I need benchmarks of Apache Geode maybe in comparison with Redis or Hazelcast. Would be appreciated if someone could point me to such.

In one of presentations of Pivotal I saw some benchmarks but they just shown that "Geode is faster than Cassandra" in some unknown aspects and they promised to publish benchmarks but I cannot find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend to build your own benchmark for your own workload. Extrapolating the result of random benchmarks (especially the ones done by the vendors themselves) to your own business will likely lead to poor results.

Anyway, if you still want a benchmark:
https://hazelcast.com/resources/benchmark-pivotal-gemfire-vs-hazelcast/

Note: Apache Geode is the open-source version of Gemfire

Comment: Thank you! I totally agree that better to build own benchmarks. But would be curious to look the version of benchmarks GemFire vs. Hazelcast but created by Pivotal.